# in Visual Studio 2022, Break point is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, breakpoints, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

When i put a break point on code line in visual studio 2022 it didn't stop on that line.

I'm trying to develop an Asp.Net Core Mvc project. I had a more project too. And break point is not working in that project too. But when i try to type code in Console Application and i want to put a break point it's working.

I watched videos on youtube.
I visited Microsoft Web Site.

[image]

Comment: Are you running your program in Debug mode?

Comment: Yes, i'm absolutely sure for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hot Reload doesnt work in Visual Studio 2022 - C# (No code changes were found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076609/hot-reload-doesnt-work-in-visual-studio-2022-c-sharp-no-code-changes-were-fou)

Comment: issue with visual studio can be solved by reinstall I think. If it's a common issue for an IDE tool, I think it should be solved very quickly...

Comment: Please show the source code where you try to set the breakpoint

Comment: It's not necessary to post the image you've included. You could have simply written *I've enabled both this and this*. Images should be used ONLY when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for a list of the many reasons not to use images in your post. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.